# Google Chrome lost its "Search Google for …" right-click option

Tags: google-chrome, right-click

For some reason I've lost the right click option 'Search Google for …', so I'm down to copy and paste.

How do I re-enable this option?

Comment: Windows, Mac or Linux? Have you tried reinstalling?

Comment: See if Google is still listing in your search engines: Wrench Icon -> Preferences - Then look at the section labelled *Search* and click *Manage Search Engines*.

Comment: What exactly do you see in the context-menu? What are you expecting it for? (it only shows for selected text; it does not display for links, images, and such)